# No 'Compress this drive to save disk space box"

Tags: hard-drive, compression, windows-10-preview

I have two external hard drives, both with NTFS, one of them allows me to compress it, the other doesn't, why?

[image: Both disk properties side by side]

https://goo.gl/photos/AqV5V42dEY5N2o569

I deleted titanfall and bf4, freed up some space, still no option:

https://goo.gl/photos/y1gFU1uKYuLuk9qC7

Comment: Probably because of the amount of available free space to do the compression...

Comment: I'll have a go deleting some games, but if that was the case I would expect it to be greyed out, not invisible.

Comment: Are all folders on this external drive owned by your user?

Comment: I am the only user, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Microsoft TechNet forum answer:

> In my experience these are two reasons to not showing this check box:
>
> 1. NTFS compression is a function of the NTFS file system and as such is available only on volumes formatted with NTFS.
> 2. The compression algorithms in NTFS support cluster sizes of up to 4 KB. When the cluster size is greater than 4 KB on an NTFS volume,
>      none of the NTFS compression features are available.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c3a874fa-bc57-481c-adc1-d58ac9b9ce20/missing-checkbox-for-compress-disk-drive-to-save-space?forum=winserverfiles

Check your NTFS cluster size to see if this is the reason as, per your picture, the drive is already NTFS.

Comment: Indeed, it is 8kb, thank you https://goo.gl/photos/jRXAdK4SpL7VYxwUA